# How to Sum Conditional Data in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a table called tbl_sale and there are seven columns in this table 
I want to sum those quantity which is returned to the shop which is in negative

so that I show how many quantity has been returned

Comment: Thanks for your post! Please note that signatures are not something we prefer to have in posts here; your post should contain only the actual content of your answer. There is a 'user box' which displays your basic information and name, and you may use your profile to post any more detailed information about you that you wish - including links to your website, projects, or product. See the "Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings." item in our Help Center in the [What kind of behavior is expected of users](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) topic.

Answer (score 0):

Create these formula fields:

```
// {@fields}
{table.amount_0}+{table.amount_1}

// {@negative}
If {@fields}<0 Then
  {@fields}
```

Insert a summarized field on the `{@negative}` formula.